# Avoiding a cast when using Option.fold in scala

Tags: scala

I am wondering if there were a construction of the `Option.fold` that would make the following `None.**.asInstanceOf[Option[String]**` unnecessary:

```
def getHiveDir(sqlc: SQLContext, tname: String, partColVals: Seq[(String, String)]): Option[String] = {
     getHiveDir(sqlc, tname).fold(None.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]) { tloc =>
           // some stuff
  }
  Some(someString)
 }
```

As it stands the above `.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]` is required or a compilation error occurs: the None is not recognized as being an `Option[String]`

How can the above code be rearranged  to avoid that extra cast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick your favorite:

```
scala> Option.empty[String]
res1: Option[String] = None

scala> None: Option[String]
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> None.asInstanceOf[Option[String]]
res3: Option[String] = None
```

You can also define the type argument explicitly for `fold`:

```
scala> val o: Option[Int] = None
o: Option[Int] = None

scala> o.fold[Option[Int]](None)(_ => Some(2))
res5: Option[Int] = None
```

There are cases where type inference just has not enough information to figure out the type. It happens in other languages like Haskell. So usual ways to help it is either specify the type with `:` or by explicitly passing type arguments like in the examples above.

Comment: "favorite"  I guess you mean "Least ugly".  I'll go with your first one - Option.empty[Type]

Comment: I like your last "option" better.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

If you're using scalaz, you can simply use `none[String]`.

Comment: I work in a variety of environments and consistently champion Scala. But I'm not about to make the world even *more* challenging to non-Scala programmers by adding scalaz/shapeless. Those are for shops with a staff already solid in the language.